# class_copyMethodList is not working on a Swift class

Tags: swift, runtime

How I can get all methods names from swift class? I try used ***class_copyMethodList***, but it is not working for swift...
I need get all methods names including all extension of my class.

1. How I can do it for clear Swift class?

Global task: I need get all methods names from my class, filtered it by prefix, and call it one by one.

Answer (score 3):

`class_copyMethodList` is a function from the ObjectiveC runtime. As expected, it only works on Objective C classes. Make your class inherit from `NSObject`:

```
class MyClass: NSObject {
    // ....
}
```

Comment: No such thing for Swift that I've heard of. Reflection in Swift is a very limited affair

Comment: Note that this will expose only the `@objc` methods of that class. `@nonobjc` ones won't show up in that list.